# Circular dependencies in ionic application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, circular-dependency

I had a Ionic 3 application that i need to upgrade to Ionic 4. In this migration, some of the circular dependencies became problematic, and I wonder what is the best way to resolve them.

I manage to resolve all others but I have problems with these two :

- A page calls a provider, and in the provider I have a function that displays a modal with this page as a component

=> FooProvider imports myPage and myPage imports FooProvider

FooProvider

```
import { myPage} from '../../pages/mypage/mypage';
this.modalCtrl.create({
          component: myPage
});
```

mypage

```
import { FooProvider } ...;
...
constructor(public provider: FooProvider ...) {
```

I could create a modalProvider that takes an argument as a string and dispatch the right page but it looks like an ugly tricks, and a provider ModalController is already defined by Ionic.

--EDIT Moved other circular dependency to another question

any idea about the best practices to avoid those kind of circular dependencies ?

thanks by advance

Comment: I made a little edition to resume quickly where the circular dependency is. Quickly, is the first case, FooProvider imports myPage and myPage imports FooProvider, and in the second case, ServerProvider imports ParametreModel and ParametreModel imports ServerProvider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A helpful rule of thumb is a separation of concern.

1- A component/Page deals with displaying stuff only

2- A provider/service deals with getting the data, or do some hard work only

3- Never Import **A** in **B** and then **B** in **A**. If you find yourself doing that, chance are you haven't given it a good thought. Try again using 1, 2 rules

To solve your first issue, I would remove the logic of presenting a modal from the provider and place it either on the page I am working on (if it is very specific to that page) or, put that logic in the app.component.ts (if this modal can be presented at different situations such as a warning/error/info message)

Now your provider may still need to present some information through a modal right? So how do we do that?
One way can be to create a **modalSubject: Subject**

FooProvider

```
import { ParametreModel } from './../../models/parametre.model';
export class ConnectionServerProvider {
    public parametre: ParametreModel;
    public modalSubject: Subject<ParametreModel> = new Subject<ParametreModel>();
    // ...

    // Then something happens and you need that parameter to sent to the model
    this.parametre = someDataFromSomeWhere;
    this.modalSubject.next(this.parametre);
}
```

Now in your Page, where FooProvider is injected, you can subscribe to that observable subject and present your modal with the data it gives you:

In mypage.ts or app.component.ts

```
constructor(private foo: FooProvider) {}
ngOnInit() {
   this.foo.modal.modalSubject.subscribe(
     (param: ParametreModel) => {
          if(!param) {
             yourFunctionThatPresentsTheModalWithParam(param);
          }
     }
   )
}
```

And voila!

Make sure you unsubscribe of that subject at your ngOnDestroy.

Can you create another question for your second question so that people having the same issue can find it?

Comment: thanks a lot ! I didn't want to put the modal creation function in the page because it is not specific to this page, but I didn't think I could place this function in components. But in components I display this page (on first lines where I display the "entry app page". Will it cause a circular dependency too ? 
I will create another question for the other circular dependency with serverprovider

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by  [on first lines where I display the "entry app page"]. Like I mentioned, if the modal is not specific to that Page, then it is better to display it from app.component.ts by subscribing to that observable modalSubject that I added to your FooProvider

Comment: oh ok I didn't understand, I thank I would have to import app component in my page to call the function. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No, you certainly don't have to do that!! the app.component is always alive in your app unlike all other pages that come and go. So it makes sense to delegate some generic modals to it.
Never important a component in another component to display a Modal. use lazy loading instead by passing page name (string) to your modal controller.